# Problems finding X11 libraries trying to build another program on Mac

Tags: macos, makefile, x11, xquartz

In the process of trying to build some software [AVL](https://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/avl/) I'm getting some X11 library issues.  I've done this install a few years ago and remember it being straight forward, but it was on an older version of OS el capitan I think and I'm on a "lite" version of Big Sur. I installed XQuartz and I can see the files it's expecting, but it seems to have trouble with the path to X11 per my understanding of this error

```
In file included from xwin11/Xwin2.c:74:
/usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h:44:10: fatal error: 'X11/X.h' file not found
```

In order for it to find Xlib.h I modified this (which I'm pretty sure isn't correct)
from

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/cursorfont.h>
```

to

```
#include </usr/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h>
#include </usr/X11/include/X11/Xutil.h>
#include </usr/X11/include/X11/cursorfont.h>
```

Before it would die on finding Xlib.h.  It also seems to be ignoring the linking line I gave it in the config.make file

```
LINKLIB = -I/usr/X11/include -L/usr/X11/lib -lX11
```

Is there an environment variable or path I'm missing in my profile?  Is it ignoring the linking flag. Or did I set this up incorrectly in the config file?  What's really odd is that now it's finding Xlib.h but it can't find X.h and they live in the same folder, which really makes me think it just doesn't know where to find the X11 "stuff" .

Thanks!

Comment: `-I` is not a linker option.  It's a compiler option (technically it's a preprocessor option).  You have to add it to your compile line (e.g., `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`), not `LINKLIB`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to solve it:

- determine from the compiler messages what include files the compiler cannot find
- find them yourself
- tell the compiler where they are
- repeat above steps for libraries it cannot link

---

So, it cannot find `Xlib.h`. Let's find that:

```
find / -name Xlib.h 2>/dev/null
```

and, on my machine, I find:

```
/opt/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h
```

So that means I need to tell the compiler where to look for header files like this:

```
g++ -I /opt/X11/include ...
```

Then, when it encounters this in your code:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
```

that means it will actually be expecting to find:

```
/opt/X11/include/X11/Xlib.h
```

---

Now, let's do the libraries:

```
find / -name libX11.dylib 2> /dev/null
```

and, on my machine, I find:

```
/opt/X11/lib/libX11.dylib
```

so that means I need:

```
g++ -I /opt/X11/include -L /opt/X11/lib/ ...
```

Comment: Yes I got the first part of this and was able to locate them.  I was just missing how to tell it where they were.  Also this is way way off of the install instructions lol but thank you.  adding the -I to the compile line and not in linking was what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MadScientist your comment was the key.  I moved the

```
-I/usr/X11/include
```

out of the linking flag and into the compile flag and that solved it!